# How do I define *start* and *end* tags when using the Stax parser?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I have a large XML file and I need to parse a few elements from it.

```
<root>
    <head>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ele1>value</ele1>
        <ele2>
            <suvEle1>value</suvEle1>
        </ele2>
        <ele3>
            <suvEle1>value</suvEle1>
        </ele3>
    </body>
</root>
```

I want to read all elements inside `<body>`. But – except `<body>` tag – all other tags inside `<body>` are dynamic. How do I define *start* and *end* tags when using the Stax parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamConstants.html#START_ELEMENT) and [XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamConstants.html#END_ELEMENT) to determine start and end tags. Something like the following.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public static void testStaxParser() {
        String xmlSource = "<root>" +
                        "<head>" +
                            "<version>1.1</version>" +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body>" +
                            "<ele1>value</ele1>" +
                            "<ele2>" +
                                "<suvEle1>value</suvEle1>" +
                            "</ele2>" +
                            "<ele3>" +
                                "<suvEle1>value</suvEle1>" +
                            "</ele3>" +
                        "</body>" +
                    "</root>";      

        try {
            XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader reader = 
                factory.createXMLStreamReader(
                        new StringReader(xmlSource));

            while(reader.hasNext()){
                int parseEvent = reader.next();

                if (parseEvent == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){ 
                    if ("body".equals(reader.getLocalName())) {
                         System.out.println("Start of body element.");
                         processElements(reader);
                         return;
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

    }

public static void processElements(XMLStreamReader reader) throws XMLStreamException {  
        do {
            int parseEvent = reader.next();

            switch(parseEvent){
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: 
                    System.out.println("Start of element " + reader.getLocalName());                  
                  break;

                case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                    System.out.println("Element content is " + reader.getText().trim());

                    break;

                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                    if ("body".equals(reader.getLocalName())) {
                        System.out.println("End of body element.");
                        return;
                    }

                    System.out.println("End of element " + reader.getLocalName());
                  break;
            }           
        } while (reader.hasNext());
    }
```